# php- Drop down value from table is not displaying?

Tags: php

Getting values from database but unable to show in drop down list.

Values are in the form of arrays.

can any one tell where i have gone wrong.

Below is my code.

```
<tr class="form-field" id="appid">
<div>
<th valign="top" scope="row" >
<label for="country"><?php _e('country', 'custom_table_example')?></label>
</th>
<td>     
<select id="country" name="country" class="code" >
<option value="">select country</option>
<?php $coun_name = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("select country_name FROM countries ") ); 
foreach($coun_name as $a){?>
<option value="<?php echo strtolower($a); ?>"><?php echo $a; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
  </select>
    </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: @jason values are not even coming if i put this query                                $coun_name = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("select country_name FROM countries ") ); and half of the page wont reload

Comment: What is the result if print_r($coun_name); ?? Also Do you have global $wpdb; defined before using it

Comment: if i put the same query out of body then values are displayed

Comment: @Poria if i print values are displaying fine in drop down its not displaying

Comment: Can i see the result in question ?

Comment: Need the value of $coun_name and you don't need to start and stop php so much. It looks a lot more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: if i put query outside body Print_r values ar displayed else no.

Comment: @Poria  i have posted screen shoot of $coun_name values

Answer (score 0):

This should work and to me a lot easier to read.

```
<?php
  $coun_name = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("select country_name FROM countries ") ); 
  foreach($coun_name as $a){
    echo '<option value="'. strtolower($a) .'"/>' . "$a </option>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: _e --->return or echo the translated string.

Comment: Are you working in wordpress? I'm not. When I ran you whole code that was the only thing giving me a problem. my test array is $coun_name = array('aaa','bbb','bb','cc'); . Commenting that out the _e let my code work.